# undefined variable error when variable is defined in the same line

Tags: python, numpy, variables

When I try setting up an array using Numpy like so:

```
def Landcover_Crops_nr(polygons):
    dataset = ee.Image("USGS/GFSAD1000_V0").clip(polygons)
    type_crop = dataset.select("landcover")
    arr = np.array(type_crop)
values, frequencies= np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)
sum = np.sum(frequencies)
percentages = [x/sum*100 for x in frequencies]
```

I get the error: "message": "Undefined variable 'arr'".

What cam I do to fix this?

Comment: Please show more code.

Comment: You **must** provide a [mcve]. Your code would throw a `NameError` for `np`...

Comment: Updated original post with additional lines of code

Comment: u should say "arr" is global
        def Landcover_Crops_nr(polygons):
            global arr
            dataset = ee.Image("USGS/GFSAD1000_V0").clip(polygons)
            type_crop = dataset.select("landcover")
            arr = np.array(type_crop)

Comment: You have to indent the last 3 lines to the same indentation as the `arr = ...` line

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer Tiago? I am not 100% sure what you are aiming at.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: it seems you have wrong indentations - and it changes everything. But if indentations are correct then you create `arr` inside function which creates local variable and it will be not avaliable outside function. You would have to use `global arr` inside function to inform function that `arr = ...` has to assign to external/global variable instead of creating local variable. OR you shoudl use `return arr` and run it as `arr  = Landcover_Crops_nr(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for me you have wrong indentations and this make all problem.

```
# --- function ---

def Landcover_Crops_nr(polygons):
    dataset = ee.Image("USGS/GFSAD1000_V0").clip(polygons)
    type_crop = dataset.select("landcover")
    arr = np.array(type_crop)
    values, frequencies = np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)
    sum = np.sum(frequencies)
    percentages = [x/sum*100 for x in frequencies]

# --- outside function ---
```

But if indentations are OK then you have to know that function creates local variable `arr` and it doesn't exists outside function.

You would have to use `global arr` to inform function that you want to assign to external/global variable. And don't forget to execute this function before you use `arr` outside function.

```
# --- function ---

def Landcover_Crops_nr(polygons):
    global arr

    dataset = ee.Image("USGS/GFSAD1000_V0").clip(polygons)
    type_crop = dataset.select("landcover")
    arr = np.array(type_crop)

# --- outside function ---

Landcover_Crops_nr(polygons)  # execute function to create variable `arr`

values, frequencies= np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)
sum = np.sum(frequencies)
percentages = [x/sum*100 for x in frequencies]
```

But better use `return arr` - it will be more readable. And assign result to external `arr`

```
# --- function ---

def Landcover_Crops_nr(polygons):
    dataset = ee.Image("USGS/GFSAD1000_V0").clip(polygons)
    type_crop = dataset.select("landcover")
    arr = np.array(type_crop)

    return arr    

# --- outside function ---

arr = Landcover_Crops_nr(polygons)  # execute function to get local `arr` and assign to global `arr`

values, frequencies= np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)
sum = np.sum(frequencies)
percentages = [x/sum*100 for x in frequencies]
```